How to insert line in Watch window in Visual Studio 2022?
I have a long list of variables in Watch 1 window of Visual Studio 2022 and want to add a new variable between others to keep related variables close.
The only things I could do is to add at the end of the list or rename the existing variable.
Is there a chance to add a line in Watch window?

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-rearranging-of-items-in-the-watch-window/836747

@HansPassant, thanks. Strange prioritization from MS on this request. Don't really people have to debug something really complex? I have dozens of variables and arrays to track and alphabetical sorting won't help at all. Any real life experience I am missing that replaces this?
